# Scrapy don't crawl over site

Tags: scrapy

I have common trap and can't get rid with it: my Scrapy spider very lazy, so that it is, it can parse only start_urls. Code below:

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.item import Field
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class HabraPostSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'habrapost'
    allowed_domains = ['habrahabr.ru']
    start_urls = ['https://habrahabr.ru/interesting/']


    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info('A response from %s just arrived!', response.url)


    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor()),
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/post/'),),callback='parse_post',follow= True))
```

I will be very happy if anybody could say how to fix my spider!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your english is totally broken but reading between the lines what I understand is that you want the crawler to go into every link it sees.

For that you have to use `CrawlSpider` instead of `Spider`

```
class HabraPostSpider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider)
```

Check [the documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example).

Comment: But `scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider` actually